# Drawing emojis on Android canvas using unicode values

Tags: java, android, canvas, unicode, emoji

I am trying to create a *custom view* for my android app. In the `OnDraw` function I am trying to draw an *emoji* by using its `unicode` value, but that does not seem to work. Following is the code:

```
public class Scale extends View {
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final static int LINE_WIDTH = 10;
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(LINE_WIDTH);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        ...
        ...
        //This works
        canvas.drawText("My text", 0.05f*width, 0.80f*height, mPaint);
        //But this does NOT draw a doughnut!!
        String s = new String(Character.toChars(0x1F369)); //Doughnut
        canvas.drawText(s, 0.75f*width, 0.50f*height, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Anyone knows if there any is work-around here? Or am I doing something wrong?

***EDIT [second question]:*** With the hack I submitted below, I see that the Emojis are rendering inside the `TextView` drawn on the `Canvas` but they are significantly **duller** compared to Emojis set on a normal TextView, as shown below:

[image]

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I have found a hack for this, which I myself don't like much! In this, I create a `Layout` (e.g. `LinearLayout`) and add a `TextView` which contains my emoji and then draw the `Layout` on `Canvas`.

```
public class Scale extends View {
    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private final LinearLayout layout;
    ...
    ...
    public Scale(final Context context, ...) {
        super(context);
        ...
        ...
        //Initialise the layout & add a TextView with the emoji in it
        layout = new LinearLayout(context);
        final TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        tv.setText(new String(Character.toChars(0x1F369))); //Doughnut
        layout.addView(tv);
        layout.measure(50, 50);
        layout.layout(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        ...
        ...
        canvas.translate(20, 20); //Translate if necessary
        //Draw the layout on the canvas, draws a doughnut!!
        layout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Please post, if there is a better solution.

**EDIT**

I figured out that [StaticLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) is a better option to draw text on canvas & *does not have the issue of the text/emoji becoming duller*.

My modified code (fewer lines than earlier):

```
public class Scale extends View {
    private final TextPaint tPaint = new TextPaint();
    private final StaticLayout lsLayout;
    ...
    ...
    public Scale(final Context context, ...) {
        super(context);
        ...
        ...
        //Initialise the layout & add a TextView with the emoji in it
        String emoji = new String(Character.toChars(0x1F369))); //Doughnut
        lsLayout = new StaticLayout(emoji, tPaint, 80, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1, 1, true);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        ...
        ...
        canvas.translate(20, 20); //Translate if necessary
        //Draw the layout on the canvas, draws a doughnut as bright as the rest of the canvas!!
        lsLayout.draw(canvas);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

Here is the result, the emojis are as bright as the rest of the drawing on the canvas:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your emoji character is outside the range of 0000 - FFFF
so it can not be represented as a single unicode character.

It may be possible if you properly encode "unicode surrogate pairs" for the emoji.

There is a calculator for determining correct surrogate-pairs of mulitbyte unicode
at: http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/surrogatepaircalculator.htm

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to help:

       `String s = new String(Character.toChars(0xD83C)) + new String(Character.toChars(0xDF69)) ; //Doughnut
        canvas.drawText(s, 0.75f*width, 0.50f*height, mPaint);`